# Combining ffmpeg filters leads to sound distortion

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to remove silence from the start and end of a recording:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -af "silenceremove=1:0:0.03, areverse, silenceremove=1:0:0.03, areverse" output.webm
```

I've found that chaining the filters like this causes distortion (clicks) in the generated output file. If I split out these filters to separate commands, it sounds perfect.

Is there a way to clean up this distortion while still chaining the filters?

Comment: Does the input have video?

Comment: @Mulvya no, just audio

Comment: Why the multiple filters? silenceremove has an option to remove from end of audio.

Comment: @Mulvya I tried to use a single filter but couldn't get it working. This works, there's just a bit of distortion. I suppose the question still stands even if there's a more efficient way to achieve what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This was bug in FFmpeg areverse filter. It is fixed in last master version.